# PHP and long UNC paths (Windows)

Tags: php, windows

Starting with PHP 7.1, long Windows path are usable, as mentioned [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.windows-support.php) (second to last paragraph of first section): "Long paths support is transparent. Paths longer than 260 bytes get automatically prefixed with `\\?\`. The max path length is limited to 2048 bytes."

This works fine for local files (i.e. "C:" drive), but not for UNC paths.

There is an equivalent to `\\?\` for those, `\\?\UNC\`, but it doesn't seem to work/be implemented.

Am I missing something?  Is it a 'bug'?  Is it planned for the future?

```
<?php

$longPathLocal = 'C:\Path\Longer\Than\260\Characters\File.ext';
$longPathUNC = '\\\Server\Path\Longer\Than\260\Characters\File.ext';

echo filesize($longPathLocal);  // Shows size of file
echo filesize($longPathUNC);    // Shows nothing (returns false)

//Tried $longPathUNC = '\\\?\UNC\Server...', but same result
```

Windows Explorer doesn't allow you to create a filename longer than 260 characters.  You have to create a couple of very long sub-folders, then move a file there with a name that will make the complete path exceed 260 characters.

Here's a code sample that demonstrate the issue, writing files on both local and UNC:

```
$roots = ['Local' => 'C:\TestDocs\\',
          'UNC'   => '\\\server\TestLongUNC\\'];
foreach($roots as $loc => $path) {
    //Create long sub-folder structure
    echo $loc.' root:   '.$path.PHP_EOL;
    $len = strlen($path);
    $fold_len = 150 - $len;
    $newFold = generateRandomString($fold_len);
    $path .= $newFold;
    // $path is now 150 char. long
    mkdir($path);
    $newFold = generateRandomString(90);
    $path .= '\\'.$newFold;
    // $path is now 240 char. long
    mkdir($path);

    //Create both short and long filenames
    $path .= '\\';
    $files = ['Short' => 'Short.txt', // Total len.: 251
              'Long'  => 'LongerFilenameAbove260Chars.txt'];  // Total len.: 273
    foreach ($files as $size => $fname) {
        $fpath = $path.$fname;
        if (@file_put_contents($fpath, 'I\'m the '.$size.' file.')) {
            echo $size.' file written';
        } else {
            echo 'Unable to write '.$size.' file';
        }
        echo ' to '.$fname.' (total path length: '. strlen($fpath).' chars)'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL.'========================='.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
}

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: Can you share some relevant code?

Comment: Does a short UNC path work (eg. does the webuser has appropriate permissions for the network share?)

Comment: Yes, a short UNC path is working.